# typeahead in javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typeahead

I'm trying to create a typeahead with the following code:

```
function makeTypeahead($container, schedule){
    if(schedule !==undefined && schedule.classes!== undefined){
        $.each(schedule.classes, function(value){
            if(value.passed === false){
                $container
                .find('.activeClasses')
                .typeahead({
                    source : Fp.pluck(schedule.classes, 'className'),
                    items  : 15
                }); 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

//In this code, typeahead doesn't work at all. (nothing shows in typeahead dropdown)

I have also tried:

```
function makeTypeahead($container, schedule){
    //All non-passed classes
    if(schedule !==undefined && schedule.classes !== undefined){

        for(var i=0; i<schedule.classes.length; i++){
            if(schedule.classes[i].passed === false){
                console.log(schedule.classes[i].passed);
                $container
                .find('.activeClasses')
                .typeahead({
                    source : Fp.pluck(schedule.classes[i], 'className'),
                    items  : 15
                }); 
            }
        }
```

//in this code, typeahead doesn't work at all. (nothing shows in typeahead dropdown)

I have a list of schedules and the classes are every class in the schedule. I want to be able to say that if the class is NOT passed, don't allow it in the typeahead.

This is done on a twitter bootstrap popup. the html is using mustache - for example: (I cant get the full html to show, I guess I'm not formatting it right for stackoverflow)

```
input id="{{stnId}}"
value="{{stnValue}}"
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I feel like I'm so close to getting it to work.

Comment: Is the console.log outputting? And if you put in a console.log($container), what do you see?

Comment: yes @MikeManfrin console.log will output all of the ones that are false, like it should. I added a console.log($container)and it shows it correctly too. It's like it's working until it actually gets to the typeahead part....

Comment: Try adding `Fp.pluck(schedule.classes[i], 'className')` in to an anonymous function, a la `function(){Fp.pluck(schedule.classes[i], 'className')}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function makeTypeahead($container, schedule){
        //Need All non-passed classes.
        if(schedule !==undefined && schedule.classes !== undefined){
            var notPassed = Fp.filter(schedule.classes, function (class) { return !class.passed; });
                    $container
                    .find('.activeClasses')
                    .typeahead({
                        source : Fp.pluck(notPassed, 'className'),
                        items  : 15
                        });
        }
    }
```